# Why could `rb_sysopen` not be found anymore by the custom fact since the upgrade to Puppet4?

Tags: ruby, puppet, facter

The following [custom fact](https://github.com/030/puppet-packer/blob/master/lib/facter/latest_packerversion.rb):

```
# returns latest packerversion, e.g. 0.10.1
Facter.add("latest_packerversion") do
  setcode do
    url="https://www.packer.io/downloads.html"

    file = open("#{url}")
    contents = file.read()

    match = contents.match(/Latest\sversion:\s(.*)</)
    match[1]
  end
end
```

worked using puppet `3.6.2`, but since the upgrade to `4.5.2` the [following issue](https://github.com/030/puppet-packer/issues/4) occurs:

```
Error: Facter: error while resolving custom fact "latest_packerversion":
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://www.packer.io/downloads.html
```

**Analysis**

- It seems that the `rb_sysopen` could not be found anymore for some reason (`No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`) since the upgrade to Puppet 4.
- Puppet4 seems to use an embedded ruby version instead of the one installed on the host (Puppet3):

> [Puppet 4, both Facter 2.4 and CFacter 0.4, the latest Hiera and
>   Mcollective, as well Ruby 2.1.5, OpenSSL 1.0.0r, and our gem
>   dependencies.](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.0/reference/release_notes.html#all-in-one-packaging)

- Does `rb_sysopen` not exist in Ruby 2.1.5? No evidence was found.
- Perhaps a change related to facts have occurred that could cause the issue? Nothing related was found [in the release notes](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.0/reference/release_notes.html#puppet-4.0-release-notes).

**Question**

Why could `rb_sysopen` not be found anymore by the custom fact since the upgrade to Puppet4?

Comment: Is this Facter 2 or Facter 3? Facter 3 was rewritten in c++11. Also, this is not what Facter was meant to do (it is for collecting server information). You may want to consider another tool.

Comment: @MattSchuchard What tool do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Concise**

I will include `require 'open-uri'` in both facts, but I do not understand why this is required since the upgrade to Puppet4

**Verbose**

Once `require 'open-uri'` is included in one of the custom facts the issue is solved.

```
# returns latest gitversion, e.g. 2.8.2
Facter.add("latest_gitversion") do
  setcode do
require 'open-uri'

    url="https://git-scm.com/downloads"

    file = open("#{url}")
    contents = file.read()

    match = contents.match(/RelNotes.*((\d\.){2}\d)/)
    match[1]
  end
end
```

As soon as the `require 'open-uri'` has been commented out, the issue occurs again:

```
Error: Facter: error while resolving custom fact "latest_gitversion": No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://git-scm.com/downloads
Error: Facter: error while resolving custom fact "latest_packerversion": No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://www.packer.io/downloads.html
```

At the moment it is unclear what is causing the issue.

Comment: You are retrieving information via http/apache so `open-uri` is necessary here.

Comment: But why did no issue occur when puppet3 was used?

Comment: Probably you were using Facter 2 and it was requiring/including `open-uri` higher up, and you are now using Facter 3 and it is not because of the rewrite.

Comment: @MattSchuchard `/opt/puppetlabs/bin/facter --version: 3.2.0`

Comment: @MattSchuchard Could you post your explanation and suggested workaround as an answer?

Comment: You answered it already, so maybe just edit your answer to include something about the change in included gems inside Facter once the http code changed from ruby to c++11.